# Setting up SDL on Visual Studio with CMake

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, cmake, sdl

My primary IDE is Visual Studio 10.0, so MSVC is my compiler. I'm building a CMake-based project, and need to install SDL and SDL_Mixer. What's the proper way to go about this, so CMake recognizes I have these things installed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure your development machine will only compile if you have sdl set the REQUIRED flag on the find_package call like:

```
find_package ( SDL REQUIRED )
find_package ( SDL_mixer REQUIRED )
```

To make sure that SDL and SDL_mixer finds your install, set the environmental variables SDLDIR and SDLMIXERDIR to the correct directories. More information on the findSDL package can be found in the [CMake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#module%3aFindSDL).